# How do I end UILongPressGestureRecognizer with an animation?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I've animated a UIImageView with a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` like so:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        var longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("longPress"))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    func longPress()
    {
        let bounds = self.imageView.bounds
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.imageView.bounds = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.size.width + 22, height: bounds.size.height + 22)
        })

        println("user pressed on image")
    }
```

the animation just causes the UIImageview's height and width to expand on the longPress, however when the press is released, the bounds continue to grow.. How do I return the bounds of the UIImageView to the origin width and height when the press is released?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
var oldbounds:CGRect!
@IBOutlet var image: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    var longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("longPress:"))
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.01
    image.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
    image.userInteractionEnabled = true
}

func longPress(gesture:UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
{
    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began
    {
        oldbounds = self.image.bounds
    }
    else if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed
    {
        let bounds = self.image.bounds
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.image.bounds = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.size.width + 22, height: bounds.size.height + 22)
        })

        println("user pressed on image")
    }
    else
    {
        let bounds = self.image.bounds
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.image.bounds = self.oldbounds
        })

        println("user release on image")
    }
}
```

Comment: hey I want to make the animation grow a little bigger but the navigationBar covers the UIImageView if it gets to a certain size, is there anyway to overlap the NavigationBar in the animation?